# Approximate energy levels for the following potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

Let's have potential
$$
U(r) = -U_{0}e^{-\frac{r}{a}}.
$$
I need to find energy levels for particles moving in this field (for an arbitrary values of orbital number $l$). This task isn't exactly solvable, so I need some method which can help to find approximate energy levels.

What to do?

I reduced the Schrodinger equation to the form (with normalized $r \to \frac{r}{a}$ and $\Psi (r, \varphi , \theta ) = \kappa e^{-\beta r}r^{l}\kappa (r) Y_{lm}(\theta , \varphi )$)
$$
r\kappa ''  + \kappa {'}(2l + 2 - 2\beta r) + \kappa (\alpha^{2}r e^{-r} - 2\beta (l + 1)) = 0,
$$ 
where
$$
\alpha^{2} = \frac{2mU_{0}a^{2}}{\hbar^{2}}, \quad \beta^{2} = \frac{2m |E|a^{2}}{\hbar^{2}}.
$$
It would be tempting to use the approximation
$$
r \approx \frac{1 - e^{-r}}{e^{-r}},
$$
but $r e^{-r}$ didn't reduce to the normal form.

The exact solution for $l = 0$ is existed.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44942/exponential-potential-solution, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47128/exponential-potential-expx

Comment: @KyleKanos : unfortunately, it is harder, because there is $r, e^{-r}$ both in the equation. I tried to express $r$ as $r \approx \frac{1 - e^{-r}}{e^{-r}}$ near zero, but it didn't help to solve equation exactly. Also I can use quasiclassical approximation, but I believe that there is some other method.

Comment: Well, there's always the [variational method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics))

Comment: @KyleKanos : But it may help only for the ground state, doesn't it?

Comment: Correct. Guess I didn't read the "arbitrary values of $\ell$" bit. If you need an approximation, might $\exp(-x)\simeq1-x$ be too approximate an approximation?

Comment: @KyleKanos : I tried to compute the equation with this approximation. Unfortunately, even after approximation it didn't reduced to hypergeometric form. Or did you ask about the accuracy of following approximation?

Comment: I had meant that the accuracy of the approximation might not be good enough. But I guess it doesn't matter since it didn't work. I'm not sure what the next step is, I'll have to think more about this.

Comment: How do you know that you have bound states for arbitrary values of $\ell$?  How do you know that there is a single bound eigenstate of that potential, for that matter?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : unfortunately, I don't know. But I was given the task, and I don't know what method to use.

Comment: @AndrewMcAdams: well, I can certainly tell you that you wont' find any states with $\ell > U_{0}$, of course.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : but does it help to say anything definitely about states? In my opinion, it is useful if at least condition that allows to determine the spectrum is founded.